# Drawing boxes around each digit to be entered in UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, core-text

I am trying to draw boxes around each digit entered by a user in UITextField for which keyboard type is - Number Pad.

To simplify the problem statement I assumed that each of the digits (0 to 9) will have same bounding box for its glyph, which I obtained using below code:

```
func getGlyphBoundingRect() -> CGRect? {
        guard let font = font else {
            return nil
        }
        // As of now taking 8 as base digit
        var unichars = [UniChar]("8".utf16)
        var glyphs = [CGGlyph](repeating: 0, count: unichars.count)
        let gotGlyphs = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, &unichars, &glyphs, unichars.count)
        if gotGlyphs {
            let cgpath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyphs[0], nil)!
            let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgpath)
            return path.cgPath.boundingBoxOfPath
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I am drawing each bounding box thus obtained using below code:

```
func configure() {
        guard let boundingRect = getGlyphBoundingRect() else {
            return
        }
        for i in 0..<length { // length denotes number of allowed digits in the box
            var box = boundingRect
            box.origin.x = (CGFloat(i) * boundingRect.width)
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.frame = box
            shapeLayer.borderWidth = 1.0
            shapeLayer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }
    }
```

Now problem is -

If I am entering digits - 8,8,8 in the text field then for first occurrence of digit the bounding box drawn is aligned, however for second occurrence of same digit the bounding box appears a bit offset (by negative x), the offset value (in negative x) increases for subsequent occurrences of same digit.

Here is image for reference -

[image]

I tried to solve the problem by setting NSAttributedString.Key.kern to 0, however it did not change the behavior.

Am I missing any important property in X axis from the calculation due to which I am unable to get properly aligned bounding box over each digit? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The key function you need to use is:

```swift
protocol UITextInput {
   public func firstRect(for range: UITextRange) -> CGRect
}
```

Here's the solution as a function:

```swift
extension UITextField {
   func characterRects() -> [CGRect] {
      var beginningOfRange = beginningOfDocument

      var characterRects = [CGRect]()

      while beginningOfRange != endOfDocument {
         guard let endOfRange = position(from: beginningOfRange, offset: 1), let textRange = textRange(from: beginningOfRange, to: endOfRange) else { break }

         beginningOfRange = endOfRange

         var characterRect = firstRect(for: textRange)

         characterRect = convert(characterRect, from: textInputView)

         characterRects.append(characterRect)
      }

      return characterRects
   }
}
```

Note that you may need to clip your rects if you're text is too long for the text field. Here's an example of the solution witout clipping:

[image]